# notify-send not working from cron

Tags: notifications, ubuntu-14.04, cron

`* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && usr/bin/notify-send "Hello world!"`

I added the above command to the crontab, notify-send is working from terminal but not from the cron. Also checked the logs, its working every minute but notifications are not being displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why but this worked. Rather calling the notify-send directed added that in a script.

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && /bin/sh /home/notifyCustom.sh
```